# Associate a username with a workflow in the persistence store?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Im new to WF and i'm trying to build an asp.net MVC web site with several WF "wizards".  All users will be logged in using forms authentication.  The users will have many different WF workflows they can start and come back and finish at a later date.  I've added an SQL persistence store to store the state of the workflow which works so far.  However it seems to me you need to know the guid of the workflow in order to reload it and carry on.

Is there a way i can add the users username to the persistence so that i could list the users currently active work flows so they can carry on where they left off? Each user could have several active work flows at any one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The persistence store supports Persistence IO Participants which can supply values to be persisted along with the workflow.  The code is a little tricky but there are samples available, just look for PersistenceIOParticipant.